# SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

I'm trying to execute the getPendingSalesOrderIDs() method which calls upon method selectInAsending(...).

But this shows a SQLException saying 
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

**Here the db.endSelect() will close all the connections. I think the problem is with that.**

```
public ArrayList getPendingSalesOrderIDs() {

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    try {
        //ResultSet r = znAlSalesOrder.select("sono", "");
        ResultSet r = salesOrder.selectInAsending("soNo", "productionStatus = 'pending' and formatID='Zn-Al'", "soNo");
        r.beforeFirst();
        while (r.next()) {
            a.add(r.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
    return a;
}


  public ResultSet selectInAsending(String fields,String selection, String     orderField)
        {
        db = new Database();
        db.select("SELECT "+fields+" FROM "+name+" WHERE "+selection + " ORDER BY "         +orderField+ " ASC");
        this.rs=db.rs;
        db.endSelect();
        return this.rs;
        }



  public void select(String query)
  {
        if(con!=null)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println(query);
                rs = stm.executeQuery(query);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answers below are correct, I'd recommend that you read up on Connections, Statements and ResultSets and learn the common patterns of opening and closing them, especially in exceptional cases (e.g.  When an Exception is thrown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `db.endSelect()` closes your ResultSet, why not remove it (in the `selectInAsending()` method)?

You can close your ResultSet in the `getPendingSalesOrderIDs()` method like so:

```
ResultSet r = null;

try {
    ResultSet r = salesOrder.selectInAsending("soNo", "productionStatus = 'pending' and formatID='Zn-Al'", "soNo");

} catch (SQLException e) {

} finally {
    if (r != null) {
        try {
            r.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the problem is with the `db.endSelect()` call.**

Just return the resultset, and then be sure to call `rs.close()` once you are finished.  This will take care of cleaning things up.